# Does an arrayUnion cost a write count in Firestore if the elements are already present in the array field?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to find out whether arrayUnion operation still incurs the cost of a write operation if it does not modify the existing array field?

For example if we have an array [1, 2] in firestore, and I'm doing arrayUion([3]), then obviously the array will be modified to [1, 2, 3] and a write will count.

But if I am doing arrayUnion([3]) to an array that already exists as [1, 2, 3] in firestore, the array will not be modified. Will **this** incur a write cost?

Comment: This sounds like something you could test for yourself using the Firebase console to measure the write.  Be sure to execute only the one write that you have concerns about and do nothing else with the project during that time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [docs](https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/firestore/latest/FieldValue.html#.arrayUnion):

> Returns a special value that can be used with set(), create() or update() that tells the server to union the given elements with any array value that already exists on the server. Each specified element that doesn't already exist in the array will be added to the end. If the field being modified is not already an array it will be overwritten with an array containing exactly the specified elements.

Therefore when you call `arrayUnion()` it will count as one write.

Comment: Will it still count as one write even if the array is not modified by the arrayUnion()?

Comment: if you have array 1,2 in the database and u do arrayunion([1,2,3]) then you are adding 3 which is one write

Comment: I'm sorry for the confusing example. I meant the array in database is [1, 2, 3] and I'm doing arrayUnion([1, 2]).

Comment: yes it's still a write, you have 1,2,3 when you do arrayunion (1,2) then you are doing one write to modify the array

Comment: I have updated the question with a simpler example. The array will not be modified in the second case. According to docs:https://firebase.googleblog.com/2018/08/better-arrays-in-cloud-firestore.html

Answer (score 2):

As suggested by Doug Stevenson, I tested by performing only this write operations multiple times in my firebase project. It **does** incur write every time.